# Forcing the .NET JIT compiler to generate the most optimized code during application start-up

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, compiler-construction, jit

I'm writing a DSP application in C# (basically a multitrack editor). I've been profiling it for quite some time on different machines and I've noticed some 'curious' things.

On my home machine, the first run of the playback loop takes up about 50%-60% of the available time, (I assume it's due to the JIT doing its job), then for the subsequent loops it goes down to a steady 5% consumption. The problem is, if I run the application on a slower computer, the first run takes up more than the available time, causing the playback to get interrupted and messing the output audio, which is unacceptable. After that, it goes down to a 8%-10% consumption.

Even after the first run, the application keeps calling some time-consuming routines from time to time (every 2 seconds more or less), which causes the steady 5% consumption to experience very short peaks of 20%-25%. I've noticed that if I let the application run for a while these peaks will also go down to a 7%-10%. (I'm not sure if it's due to the JIT recompiling these portions of code).

So, I have a serious problem with the JIT. While the application will behave nicely even in very slow machines, these 'compiling storms' are going to be a big problem. I'm trying to figure out how to resolve this issue and I've come up with an idea, which is to mark all the 'sensible' routines with an attribute that will tell the application to 'squeeze' them beforehand during start-up, so they'll be fully optimized when they're really needed. But this is only an idea (and I don't like it too much either) and I wonder if there's a better solution to the whole problem.

I'd like to hear what you guys think.

(NGEN the application is not an option, I like and want all the JIT optimizations I can get.)

EDIT:

Memory consumption and garbage collection kicks are not an issue, I'm using object pools and the maximum peak of memory during playback is 304 Kb.

Comment: It would help if you said **why** NGEN is not an option; understanding the problem is half the job...

Comment: What JIT optimizations are not available when NGen-ing?

Comment: @Marc: I'd NGen the app as a last resort, but I'd rather to not using it if there's a better solution available.

Comment: Then first you need to prove what the problem is. The ongoing pauses are nothing to do with JIT. JIT has no part to play once code has been visited at least once. You are going to have to profile....

Comment: @Marc: Is not the JIT able to recompile some portions of code if they're executed a certain number of times?

Comment: You do realise that NGEN _is_ JIT? It's just the jitter running over the code, and saving it, rather than doing it at runtime. There is NO difference. Also: There is no "quick and nasty" JIT vrs "slower and better" JIT. Just JIT. And you can't tweak it.

Comment: Well, it's not the same actually. By using NGEN you lose optimizations based on runtime information, and that's the only reason I'm trying to avoid using it.

Comment: @Trap: No, there's no runtime profiling going on in the .NET JITer.

Comment: @dthorpe: I'm not sure that's correct.  One of the things the JIT can do is replace property calls with direct access to the underlying field, but this can only be done during runtime, not at NGEN time.

Comment: @Steven: Replacing indirects with direct references doesn't require execution profiling.  I think what Trap is referring to is the Java Hotspot optimizer, which hasn't made an appearance in the .NET space AFAIK

Comment: @dthorpe: Are you sure?  The JIT can't tell whether the property is a thin, inlineable wrapper until that assembly is loaded, so if the calling assembly is NGENed, it would necessarily have to call the non-inlined property.

Comment: @Steven: Yes, you are correct: NGEN may codegen indirect references where the inline JIT will not.  Note that NGEN in .NET 2.0 and later eliminates many of the indirections that NGEN in .NET 1.x was infamous for.  This still doesn't change my statement: the .NET JIT compiler does not perform *recompilation of already compiled code* based on execution profiling.  What Trap asked in the comment above was whether the .NET JIT can reoptimize/recompile to native code after the code has executed a few times.  I'm not aware of anything like that in .NET.

Comment: @dthorpe: Yes, we're on the same page now. Once code is compiled, by JIT or NGEN, it stays compiled.  There's no recompiling to optimize based on profiling.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can trigger the JIT compiler to compile your entire set of assemblies during your application's initialization routine using the `PrepareMethod` ... method (without having to use `NGen`).

This solution is described in more detail here: [Forcing JIT Compilation During Runtime](http://www.liranchen.com/2010/08/forcing-jit-compilation-during-runtime.html).

Comment: Forcing JIT compilation without actually executing the methods is genius! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The initial speed indeed sounds like Fusion+JIT, which would be helped by ILMerge (for Fusion) and NGEN (for JIT); you could always play a silent track through the system at startup so that this does all the hard work without the user noticing any distortion?

NGEN is a good option; is there a *reason* you can't use it?

The issues you mention *after* the initial load do **not** sound like they are related to JIT. Perhaps garbage collection.

Have you tried profiling? Both CPU and memory (collections)?

Comment: For me the the only reason not to use ngen would be that it requires administrative privileges during installation, thus not being applicable to per-user installations on corporate networks. Maybe that is the reason for the OP as well?

Comment: Why not do NGEN as an option on install then? So if you have admin rights, do it. Otherwise warn the user and dont do it.

Answer (score 3):

As Marc mentioned, the ongoing spikes do not sound like JIT issues.  Other things to look for:

- Garbage collection - are you allocating memory during your audio processing?  If you're creating a lot of garbage, or even objects which survive a Gen 0 collection, this might cause noticible spikes.  It sounds like you are doing some kind of pre-allocation, but watch out for hidden allocations in library code (even a foreach loop can allocate!)
- Denormals.  There is an issue with certain types of processors when dealing with very small floating point numbers which can cause CPU spikes.  See http://www.musicdsp.org/files/denormal.pdf for details.

Edit:

Even if you don't want to use NGen, at least compare an NGen'd version so you can see what difference JITing makes

Comment: Interesting.  I had no clue that denormals were such a monstrous speed bump.

Answer (score 3):

If you believe you are being impacted by JIT, then precompile your app with NGEN and run the tests again.  There is no JIT overhead in code that has been compiled by NGEN.  If you still see spikes in the NGEN'd app, then you know they are not caused by JIT.